# XenServer Express/Enterprise and Citrix Essential

Tags: xen, xenserver

I'm confused with XenServer... I plan to buy a Dell R710 server and run XenServer on it. Dell can sell me a XenServer license with the server, I can choose between XenServer Express and Xen Server Enterprise. When I look at Citrix Web Site they talk about "XenServer" and "Citrix Essentials for XenServer". So, what's the difference between Dell's Express/Enterprise edition and Citrix Xenserver/Essentials?

and an other question: is XenCenter free?

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XenServer is free, Essentials and Enterprise cost some $$$. This page here ([link](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/subfeature.asp?contentID=1680964)) is the best for showing the features across the 3 editions.

**Edit:** Your post doesn't elaborate on the situation for your virtualization project, but I'd recommend *starting* with the free XenServer first. Should you need the additional features immediately, then perhaps Dell would be best as they're assembling your server.

**Edit (again):** AFAIK, XenCenter is *free* with XenServer, but I *believe* that once you move up to essentials or enterprise there are costs involved. I *can't* speak accurately about this issue but for the free edition, it *is* free with limitations.

Comment: No problem, Pol. Hope your virtualization project goes well.

Answer (score 0):

xenserver is free to my knowledge
http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/feature.asp?contentID=1686939